# UNIX script to check if httpd service is on or off and if off send a email

Tags: linux, bash, email, unix, command

Script to check if httpd is on or no

How do I make this script run in background so that it keeps checking if httpd service is on or off and emails a message if it goes off !! ( PS-: I DON'T WANT TO MAKE THE SCRIPT AS A CRONJOB) just like a daemon process which runs in background!!
               Please Help